# RequireJS Routing Removes #

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am following the tutorial here: https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs.

Problem is that when I use the routing, the # from the URL is removed; i.e. say I have `mypage.com/#/resource/` as one of my routes. Once I load that page, after a second, it becomes `mypage.com/resource/`.

So the problem now is that if I refresh the page, then I get a 404 error since I am trying to load the `resource` folder! Why?

Comment: what do your routes and links look like?

Comment: I'm following the tutorial: https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs/blob/master/app/scripts/routes.js . I'm not even in the linking yet. I just manually type in the link, and the #hashtag is removed after the page loads

Comment: and the hyperlinks you click..? like `<a href="/resource/">` or whatever

Comment: No, I click `<a href="/#/resource">`. But I am saying right now, I actually type in `/#/resource` in the browser. After the page loads, then the URL is changed to `/resource` so if I then refresh the page, I get 404 error

Comment: do u have below setup: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: @Kousha your last comment indicates that the problem has been solved. It looks like HarishR provided the solution. If this is the case then please ask HarishR to post an answer, then you should mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @HarishR, can you please post this as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to have html5 mode enabled: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Please disable it.